# IntelliJ IDEA - what setting controls the VCS branch indicator in the status bar?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using the newly released 2019.3 version.

I seem to have lost the little widget from my status bar that lets you see and manipulate the branch you're on for each of your VCS roots (I'm working in a "micro-service" environment with lots of repos, so I'm dealing with many VCS roots).

Should be like this:
[image]

But I'm seeing: [image]

Those two screenshots are actually from the same instance of idea, I have two projects open - only one of them has the missing branch indicator.

I've tried rebooting IDEA, but the branch indicator is still missing from one of them.
I've tried looking through the settings but couldn't see anything (not actually sure what the name of this feature would be, so it's difficult to search for).

**Question**: is there a setting that controls this that I've accidentally toggled in that project? 
Or maybe this is a bug.

For anyone else having this problem, as a quick workaround you can access the popup with keyboard shortcut "Ctrl + Shift + `"

Answer (score 0):

You may see such behavior if your project is not associated with Git.

In the **Settings/Preferences** dialog go to **Version Control** check whether there are any "Unregistered roots" exist - if so, once you specify the exact path to the Git directory you should be able to see Git widget again.